# Extract and count domains address mails from e-mails

Tags: python, regex, counter

I have a list of emails and would like to extract only the domains and count how many times each one appears:

**Emails:**

> best@yahoo.com
>
> hello@gmail.com
>
> everybody@gmail.com
>
> bye@gmail.com
>
> day@yahoo.com
>
> table.blue@gmail.com
>
> life@yahoo.com

**Script:**

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open("mails.txt", "r") as f:
    texte = f.read().split('\n')

    for line in texte:
        newline = re.search("@[\w.]+", line)
        newmail = newline.group()

        mails_value = Counter(newmail).most_common()

        print (mails_value)
```

**output:**

> [('@', 1), ('g', 1), ('6', 1), ('5', 1), ('.', 1), ('f', 1), ('r', 1)]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "counting.py", line 10, in
>
> ```
> newmail = newline.group()
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

**good output:**

> @yahoo.com 3
>
> @gmail.com 4

Comment: You are not counting the extracted mentions, collect them first, then find the most common, see https://ideone.com/PyxjGt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close - No need to split the file into lines, just use `re.findall`, `re.MULTILINE` and the pattern [@(.*)$](https://regex101.com/r/HdHPJ8/1/)

```
import re
import collections

with open("mails.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
domains = re.findall(r'@(.*)$', text, re.MULTILINE)
mails_value = collections.Counter(domains) 
# outputs with example: Counter({'gmail.com': 4, 'yahoo.com': 3})
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex. If you can trust that all the inputs are well formed emails, this should suffice:

```
from collections import defaultdict

domain_count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

with open("mails.txt", "r") as f:
    texte = f.readlines()

    for line in texte:
        domain = line.split('@')[-1]
        domain_count[domain] += 1

print (domain_count)
```

Comment: `defaultdict(lambda: 0)` can be written as `defaultdict(int)`. `Counter`, as used in the OP, is better for this task anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The regex will save you from creating an unnecessary list.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open("mails.txt", "r") as f:
    texte = f.read().split('\n')
    l=[]
    for line in texte:
        p=re.compile("(?<=@)[^.]+(?=\.)")
        newline = p.search(line)
        if(newline):

            newmail = newline.group(0)
            l.append(newmail)

Counter(l)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Counter({'gmail': 4, 'yahoo': 3})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use split

```
texte = "life@yahoo.com"
texte.split("@")
['life', 'yahoo.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

do 2 splits.  The second with @.. Then append the last item and apply the counter to the list

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open("mails.txt", "r") as f:
    texte = f.read().split('\n')

    domains = []

    for line in texte:
        line = line.split('@')
        if line[-1] != "":
            domains.append(line[-1])

mails_value = Counter(domains).most_common()

print(mails_value)
```

`[('gmail.com', 4), ('yahoo.com', 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

mails = []

with open("mails.txt", "r") as f:
    texte = f.read().split()
    for i in texte:
        mails.append(re.search("@[\w.]+", i).group())

mails_value = Counter(mails).most_common()
print mails_value
```

Comment: `[\w.]` is the same as `.`